# array and asynchronous function callback

Tags: javascript

I got async function:

```
var func = function  (arg, next) {
    var milliseconds = 1000;
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log (arg);
        next()
    }   , milliseconds);
}
```

And array:

```
var arr = new Array();
arr.push (0);
arr.push (1);

console.log(arr);
```

I want to use `func` for every item of my array `arr`:

```
func(arr[0], function(){
    func(arr[1], function(){
        console.log("finish");
    })
})
```

Ok for array consisted of 2 elements, but if I got array of 1000 elements how to use `func` for every item in `arr`?

How to do it in cycle?

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-large-data-processing/

Comment: are you talking about a foreach loop?

Comment: `arr.forEach(func(this));` would this work?

Comment: @TraeMoore: No, definitely not. Did you try it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var arrayFunc = function(array) {
  if (array.length > 0) {
    func(array[0], function() { arrayFunc(array.slice(1)); });
  }
}
```

This will run your function with the first element in the array, and then have the continuation function take the rest of the array.  So when it runs it will run the new first element in the array.

EDIT: here's a modified version that doesn't copy the array around:

```
var arrayFunc = function(array, index) {
  if (index < array.length) {
    func(array[index], function() {
      var newI = index + 1;
      arrayFunc(array, newI);
    });
  }
}
```

And just call it the first time with an index of 0.

Comment: I need to start thinking faster, this is the exact same solution I got to! :)

Comment: Won't `array.slice` create a new array? This would lead to O(n^2) memory consumption.

Comment: Good catch.  For small arrays it should be fine.  If dealing with large amounts of data then yes, it could be made better.  Edited to provide that option as well.

Comment: `arr.forEach(func(this));` would this work? sorry, wrong comment section

Comment: The new function doesn't work; it will forever invoke `func` with the same `index`.

Comment: Bergi: you're right.  That's what I get for not testing.  Fixing it now.

Answer (score 0):

While your approach is valid, it's not possible to use it if you have an uncertain number of calls, since every chain in your async command is hardcoded.

If you want to apply the same functionality on an array, it's best to provide a function that creates an internal function and applies the timeout on it's inner function:

```
var asyncArraySequence = function (array, callback, done){
  var timeout = 1000, sequencer, index = 0;

  // done is optional, but can be used if you want to have something
  // that should be called after everything has been done
  if(done === null || typeof done === "undefined")
    done = function(){}

  // set up the sequencer - it's similar to your `func`
  sequencer = function(){
    if(index === array.length) {
      return done();      
    } else {
      callback(array[index]);
      index = index + 1;
      setTimeout(sequencer, timeout);
    }
  };
  setTimeout(sequencer, timeout);
}

var arr = [1,2,3];
asyncArraySequence(arr, function(val){console.log(val);});
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple asynchronous loop:

```
function each(arr, iter, callback) {
    var i = 0;
    function step() {
        if (i < arr.length)
            iter(arr[i++], step);
        else if (typeof callback == "function")
            callback();
    }
    step();
}
```

Now use

```
each(arr, func);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try `arr.map`

```
var func = function  (arg, i) {
    var milliseconds = 1000;
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log (arg);
    }, milliseconds*i);
}

var arr = new Array();
arr.push (0);
arr.push (1);

arr.map(func);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/VdheQ/2/) and [**Polyfill for older browsers**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_map.htm).

**Update :** I thought the `OP` wants to loop through the array and call the callback function with each array item but I was probably wrong, so instead of deleting the answer I'm just keeping it here, maybe it would be helpful for someone else in future. This doesn't answer the current question.

Comment: What would you `map` to? Makes no sense here.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it, isn't it looping the array and calling the function ?

Comment: map doesn't help here.  He doesn't want to call func() on each element in the array immediately.  He wants to call it on the first element, and pass to that a function that calls it on the second, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be:

```
var fn = arr.reduceRight(function (a, b) {
  return func.bind(null, b, a);
}, function() {
  console.log('finish');
});

fn();
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/isuwac/2/

---

or if the order of `func`'s parameters could be changed to receive the `next` callback as the first parameter, it could be as simple as:

```
['a', 'b', 'c'].reduceRight(func.bind.bind(func, null), function (){
  console.log('finish');
})();
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/ucUZUBe/1/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

Thanx, @Herms. Working solution:

```
var arrayFunc = function(array) {
  if (array.length > 0) {
    func(array[0], function() {arrayFunc(array.slice(1)); });
  }
  else
  {
    console.log("finish");
  }
}
arrayFunc(arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can loop through the array

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    func(arr[i], function(){...});
}
```

Comment: That won't do them in sequence like he wants.  It would start them all immediately, instead of starting the next after the previous was done.